# How to do a full match of a string using regex within a document to make modifications

Tags: regex, sed, match

I have a file that looks like this called `listofnames.txt`.

```
this-is-name-1
this-is-name-2
...
this-is-name-11
this-is-name-12
this-is-name-13
this-is-name-14
...
this-is-name-21
....
```

I want to do a full match of a certain word and add a "0" next to it. I use the following command:

```
sed -i '/this-is-name-1/s/$/ 0/' ~/listofnames.txt
```

However, instead of this,

```
this-is-name-1 0
this-is-name-2
...
this-is-name-11
this-is-name-12
this-is-name-13
this-is-name-14
...
this-is-name-21
....
```

I get this,

```
this-is-name-1 0
this-is-name-2
...
this-is-name-11 0
this-is-name-12 0
this-is-name-13 0
this-is-name-14 0
...
this-is-name-21
....
```

What is wrong with my command? how do I fix it and do what I need. It seems to be doing a partial match instead of a full match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to match the word: `this-is-name-1` so that to exclude cases like `this-is-name-11` etc. There are many ways for doing this, depending the rest of your file content and what are the cases you want to protect your edit from. For example `\b` matches word bountaries, this includes white-space characters, the beginning/end of lines, and other non-alphanumeric characters. It seems good for your case:

```
sed -i '/\bthis-is-name-1\b/s/$/ 0/' file
```

You will find this read very useful: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: do you think you could look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865912/using-ssh-and-sed-within-a-python-script-with-os-system-properly the command works on its own but for some reason it doesn't work in this context

Comment: use Python `subprocess` module, recommended in that good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add start/end of string (line for sed by default) anchors:

```
sed 's/^this-is-name-1$/& 0/' file
```